# SSRS Visual Studio 2012, Report Server Template Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

When I launch VS Ultimate 2012, and select "New Project...", I do not have the option of Templates --> Reporting Services --> Report Server Project*

When I download SQL Server Data Tools for 2012, I can get to the Feature Selection screen, but everything is grayed out. Hitting "Next" presents the error message, "To continue, select a feature to install. If all features are already selected, these features are installed. You cannot add additional features."

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-1-creating-a-report-server-project-reporting-services

Comment: Did you install Reporting Services?

Comment: Hi @RossBush, I was not aware that that was an option, but didn't find anything Googling it. Do you mind linking me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ReportBuilder can run as a standalone tool, however, Reporting Projects in SSDT require some parts of the SQL Server : Reporting Services installation.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/reporting-services-in-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) link under Report Server Projects --> *When you install Reporting Services, the following project templates are made available in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT):*

Comment: Hi, unless I'm mistaken that's just part of SSDT, which I have attempted to install over and over.

Comment: I have only used Report Server projects that's why I wrote "I think". Visual Studio used to always be one version ahead of SQL Server/ Data tools. So you would have a setup like 2012 of VS and 2010 of Data Tools. I have never used the Data Tools without installing SQL Server|Reporting Services and if it is not a pre-requisite then it is news to me..